# ¿Como puedo hacer fijo el banner de cookies?

Tags: javascript, css

hola buenas como puedo hacer fijo el banner de cookies cuando hago el scroll  en moviles?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
#cookies-eu-banner {
        position: fixed;
top: 500px;
    }
    
}
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema te da ese código?

Comment: pues que al hacer scroll en moviles sube el banner y crea un espacio

Comment: ¿Pasa en todos los móviles o solo en algunos que pudieran tener mayor resolución que la que especificas? Si pasa en todos, entonces, por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/523689/edit) para poner código HTML y CSS que podamos probar con un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: es que el problema es que es un plugin de cookies de wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Tienes una llave de mas en tu código, tal vez sea eso

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #cookies-eu-banner {
        position: fixed;
        top: 500px;
    }
}
```

Comment: En css una llave de mas no suele romper por completo los estilos, por lo que dudo su problema sea eso, te recomiendo no contestar preguntas sin trabajo de investigación o almenos un [example]

Comment: Bueno tampoco es que el autor da muchos detalles... en fin

Comment: Precisamente por eso no se recomienda responder preguntas sin trabajo de investigación o suficiente detalles para saber lo que necesita exactamente. Tambien puedes leer [answer]

Answer (score -1):

al final lo puse asi  `#cookies-eu-banner { position: fixed; {` y me funciona